# Redirect to login control of the application-Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page which has URL to 3 application. Instead of redirecting to URL, I need to place a login control which should redirect to the login page of the other application. How can I achieve this in asp.net application?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["userid"])))  
        {  
          Response.Redirect("login.aspx?url=" + 
                                 Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));  
        }
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/redirect-to-clicked-page-after-login/

Comment: Note that this approach is potentially insecure... Ensure that for the URL you only accept relative, not absolute addresses... Otherwise people can co-opt your login process to redirect users.

Comment: Can you give more of an example of what your talking about ?

Comment: See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet for a primer. Edit: Apologies, I mis-read your code. I thought you were accepting the new URL in the request, rather than using the URL from the request that invoked this page.